# vue js axios open new window and watch for callback

Tags: express, vue.js, axios, vuex, steam-web-api

My goal is it to call my express js backend, which opens a window for a openid authentication. After I successfully authenticated there I want to close that window and watch from my vue js application for a callback.

This is what I have done so far. All I want is that jwt token in my frontend not only in my backend.

This is my vuex store function:

```
login({ commit } = {}) {

var loginWindow = window.open('http://localhost:3000/auth/steam', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600');
if (window.focus) {
  loginWindow.focus();
}

// return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/auth/steam',  { crossdomain: true }).then((authResponse) => {
//   console.log(authResponse)
//   return;
// }).catch((error) => {
//   console.log(error)
//   return null;
// });
},
```

And this is my express js functions:

```
app.get('/auth/steam', passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/auth/steam/return', passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/' }), (req, res) => {
  let token = jwt.sign({ user: req.user }, 'secret', { expiresIn: '2h' });

  console.log(jwt.decode(token));

  res.send(`
    <script>
      // window.opener.steamCallback({
      //   ok: true,
      //   token: '${token}'
      // });
      window.close();
    </script>
  `)
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your explanation of your goal makes sense to me. Are you running into a [specific obstacle](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @kurbo, the problem is that i can close the window i opend for the authenthification. But i have no clue how i get the token that is generated in that window back to my vue frontend application.

Comment: I think that's the intended purpose of the lines that are commented out starting with `window.opener.steamCallback({`. To pass some data into a function you provide in the parent (or "opener") window.